# how to render the updated values from the input fields in the child component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a react js parent component.When it is being called a Welcome page opens up which shows the records of the users.There is also a sign up  button on this page.When the sign up button is clicked a dialog box is opened which asks for user details.My requirement is that data should flow from the dialog box to the welcome page(along with users which were earlier rendered).It should include updated record.I have tried to use callback function.

My Todo component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Todo.css';
import FormDialog from './FormDialog';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import { thisExpression } from '@babel/types';

class Todo extends Component {
  state = {
    edit: false,
    id: null,
    view: false,
    students: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com' },
      { id: 5, name: 'kiwi', age: 20, email: 'kiwi@email.com' }
    ]
  };

  onDeleteHandle() {
    let id = arguments[0];
    this.setState({
      students: this.state.students.filter(item => {
        if (item.id !== id) {
          return item;
        }
      })
    });
  }

  onUpdateHandle(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      students: this.state.students.map(item => {
        if (item.id === this.state.id) {
          item['id'] = event.target.updatedItem.value;
          item['name'] = event.target.updatedItem1.value;
          item['age'] = event.target.updatedItem2.value;
          item['email'] = event.target.updatedItem3.value;
        }
        return item;
      })
    });
    this.setState({ edit: false });
  }

  signUpDialog() {
    this.setState({ view: true });
  }

  renderEditForm() {
    if (this.state.edit) {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}>
          <input type="text" name="updatedItem" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.id} />
          <input type="text" name="updatedItem1" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.name} />
          <input type="text" name="updatedItem2" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.age} />
          <input type="text" name="updatedItem3" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.email} />
          <button className="update-add-item">Update</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

  onEditHandle(event) {
    this.setState({ edit: true, id: arguments[0], name: arguments[1], age: arguments[2], email: arguments[3] });
  }

  onSubmitHandle(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
    this.setState({ students: [...this.state.students, { id: { p1 }, name: { p2 }, age: { p3 }, email: { p4 } }] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '500px', background: 'beige' }}>
        <form>
          <button onClick={this.signUpDialog.bind(this)}>Sign-UP</button>
          {this.state.view ? <FormDialog details={this.onSubmitHandle} /> : null}
          <table>
            {this.state.students.map(abc => (
              <tr>
                <td>{abc.id}</td>
                <td>{abc.name}</td>
                <td>{abc.age}</td>
                <td>{abc.email}</td>
                <td>
                  <button onClick={this.onDeleteHandle.bind(this, abc.id)}>Delete</button>
                </td>
                <button onClick={this.onEditHandle.bind(this, abc.id, abc.name, abc.age, abc.email)}>Edit</button>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </table>
        </form>{' '}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

The following is my child component which has a dialog box.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

class FormDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { edit: false, view: true };
    this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
  }
  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ view: !this.state.view });
  }
  onDeleteHandle() {
    let id = arguments[0];
    this.setState({
      students: this.state.students.filter(item => {
        if (item.id !== id) {
          return item;
        }
      })
    });
  }

  onEditHandle(event) {
    this.setState({ edit: true, id: arguments[0], name: arguments[1], age: arguments[2], email: arguments[3] });
  }
  onUpdateHandle(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      students: this.state.students.map(item => {
        if (item.id === this.state.id) {
          item['id'] = event.target.updatedItem.value;
          item['name'] = event.target.updatedItem1.value;
          item['age'] = event.target.updatedItem2.value;
          item['email'] = event.target.updatedItem3.value;
        }
        return item;
      })
    });
    this.setState({ edit: false });
  }

  renderEditForm() {
    if (this.state.edit) {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}>
          <input type="text" name="updatedItem" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.id} />
          <input type="text" name="updatedItem1" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.name} />
          <input type="text" name="updatedItem2" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.age} />
          <input type="text" name="updatedItem3" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.email} />
          <button className="update-add-item">Update</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

  onSubmitForm(event) {
    this.props.details(
      event.target.id.value,
      event.target.item.value,
      event.target.xyz.value,
      event.target.email.value
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog fullWidth open={this.state.view} onClose={this.handleClose.bind(this)}>
          <DialogTitle>Sign Up Provide Details</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            {this.renderEditForm()}

            <DialogContentText>
              <div>
                <form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmitForm(e)}>
                  <label>ID</label>
                  <input type="number" name="id" className="item" />
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="item" className="item" />
                  <label>age</label>
                  <input type="number" name="xyz" className="item" />
                  <label>email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="email" className="item" />
                  <button className="btn-add-item">Add</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose.bind(this)} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FormDialog;
```

As you can see the form upon submission calls a onSubmitForm() which in turns passes the values of the 4 input fields to the parent component.The values are reaching the parent component as i check with alert(p1),alert(p2),alert(p3) and alert(p4).
But i am not able to set the state of the student array as defined by using this.setState({students: [...this.state.students, {id:{p1},name:{p2},age:{p3},email:{p4}}]  }).

Any help as how i can set the state of the students array and re-render the entire array in the page.

Comment: Is there an error occurring? If yes, please share the complete stack trace of the error.
Also, why using '{}' in p1, p2..?
 Thanks

Comment: there is no error.My issue is that the table is not being re-rendered along with the new values.i.e i am not able to setState of students with the new values,

Comment: Can you try binding your `onSubmitHandle` with parent (Todo) component instead of child (FormDialog) component?

Comment: the onSubmitHandle is in Todo Component.I am passing it as a callback function to the child component.

Comment: I know but the state you want to change exists in parent component, you can try your function binding with parent component instead of a child component.

Comment: Can you tell me where in my code i should do that?

Comment: add `constructor(props){this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);}` in parent component and remove this from child `this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);`

BUT,
Before that try this:

`this.setState(prevState => ({
  students: [...prevState.students, {yourObject}]
}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

This is first one.

```
{
  id: { p1: 123 },
  name: { p2: 'test name' },
  age: { p3: 18 },
  email: { p4: 'abc@xyz.com }
}
```

But you need to generate like

```
{
  id: 123,
  name: 'test name',
  age: 18,
  email: 'abc@xyz.com
}
```

So make this change in your function.

```
onSubmitHandle(p1,p2,p3,p4) { 
  this.setState({students: [...this.state.students, {
    id:p1,
    name:p2,
    age:p3,
    email:p4
  }]})
};
```

Even better would name your argument the same as the key.

```
onSubmitHandle(id,name,age,email) { 
  this.setState({students: [...this.state.students, {
    id,
    name,
    age,
    email
  }]})
};
```

Bind your handler while passing to dialog.

```
<FormDialog details={this.onSubmitHandle.bind(this)} />
```

And you need to use event.preventDefault in your form submit action.

```
onSubmitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.details(
      event.target.id.value,
      event.target.item.value,
      event.target.xyz.value,
      event.target.email.value
    );
  }
```

I have created sandbox and fixed your issues:

[image: Edit fragrant-sun-ehflg]

Comment: I made the changes { 
  this.setState({students: [...this.state.students, {
    id,
    name,
    age,
    email
  }]})
};  but still  my issue isnt resolved.I am not able to re-render the entire array along with the new data.

Comment: can you try `details={this.onSubmitHandle.bind(this)}`?

Comment: it is getting added but the display is getting closed quickly.I mean within fraction of seconds it is getting closed.

Comment: updated answer. created codesandbox with a working example. cheers!

Comment: Hi Amit,its working .But i have one more tiny issue.When the form is submitted ,the dialog box should close.Can you please help me on that as well.Also I am able to add only 1 record.After that the sign up button is not working.

Comment: updated. just ad setState({ view:fase}) in your dialog component.

Comment: @aakritipriya I went through your questins and you don't accept answers. please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers .

Comment: @AmitChauhan I am using the same components.This time i need to perform and update operation.I have created another component as EditDialog.js and passing the values from todo to editdialog ,but i am not able to edit/update the values.Can you please help.My requirement is that the the data from the selected row should auto populate in the dialog box and once update/edit is done in the dialog box,the data should flow backl to the original table.Can you please help.

Comment: @aakritipriya this is a new issue, please create a new issue. you can mark this as accpeted as your orginal question is answered here.

Comment: @AmitChauhan i have accepted this answer.Please find the new issue at the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144843/how-to-auto-populate-data-in-the-dialog-box-in-react-js/60146536?noredirect=1#comment106381534_60146536