# how to auto populate data in the dialog box in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a root component.From that I am calling the welcome page which is displaying the details of the students already registered along with edit and delete button in each row.
The delete function is working fine which is used to delete a row,But my requirement is that when i click on the edit button,the details of the student selected, should auto populate in the dialog box and once updating is complete,the finalized result should be published back to the starting page.
App-->Todo.js-->EditDialog.js

```
App.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormDialog from './FormDialog'
import Todo from './ToDo'
import EditDialog from './EditDialog'



import './App.css';



class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mode: false
    };

  }

  showForm()
  {
    this.setState({mode:!this.state.mode})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">        
        <button onClick={this.showForm.bind(this)}>Welcome</button>
        {this.state.mode? <Todo/>:null}


        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Todo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Todo.css'
import EditDialog from './EditDialog'
import FormDialog from './FormDialog'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import { thisExpression } from '@babel/types';

class Todo extends Component {

  state = {    edit: false, id: null,view:false,editview:false,
    students: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com' },
      { id: 5, name: 'kiwi', age: 20, email: 'kiwi@email.com' }
   ], }



   onDeleteHandle() {let id = arguments[0];
    this.setState({students:this.state.students.filter(item => {if (item.id !== id)
       {return item;}})});}


  onUpdateHandle(id,name,age,email){

    this.setState({students: this.state.students.map(item => {
      if (item.id === this.state.id){
        item['id'] = id;        
        item['name']=name;
        item['age']=age;
        item['email']=email;
      }return item;})})
      this.setState({edit: false});
  }


  signUpDialog(){
    this.setState({view:!this.state.view})
  }   

  editFormDialog(){
    this.setState({editview:!this.state.editview})
  }


  renderEditForm() {
    if (this.state.edit) {
    return <form onSubmit={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}>
    <input type="text" name="updatedItem" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.id} />
    <input type="text" name="updatedItem1" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.name} />
    <input type="text" name="updatedItem2" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.age} />
    <input type="text" name="updatedItem3" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.email} />
    <button className="update-add-item">Update</button> 
    </form>    }  }


    onEditHandle(event) {
    this.setState({edit: true,id: arguments[0],name:arguments[1],age:arguments[2],email:arguments[3]});}


    onSubmitHandle(id,name,age,email) { 

      this.setState({students: [...this.state.students, {
        id:id,
        name:name,
        age:age,
        email:email
      }]})
    }; 



     render() 

          {    
           return<div style={{width: "500px",background : "beige"}} >     


                  <button onClick={this.signUpDialog.bind(this)}>Sign-UP</button>
                 {this.state.view? <FormDialog details={this.onSubmitHandle.bind(this)}/> :null}

                   <table>{this.state.students.map(abc => (<tr><td>{abc.id}</td><td>{abc.name}</td><td>{abc.age}</td><td>{abc.email}</td><td>
                    <button onClick={this.onDeleteHandle.bind(this, abc.id)}>Delete</button></td>
                    <button onClick={this.editFormDialog.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
                    {this.state.editview? <EditDialog updDetails={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}/>:null}

                    </tr>))}</table> </div>  
              }
            }

              export default Todo;
```

EditDialog.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Todo from './ToDo'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';


class EditDialog extends Component{
    constructor(props){

        super(props);
        this.state={editDetails: true,view:false}
    }
    onUpdateHandle(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({students: this.state.students.map(item => {
          if (item.id === this.state.id){
            item['id'] = event.target.updatedItem.value;        
            item['name']=event.target.updatedItem1.value;
            item['age']=event.target.updatedItem2.value;
            item['email']=event.target.updatedItem3.value;
          }return item;})})
          this.setState({edit: false});
      }
    renderEditForm() {
        if (this.state.editDetails) {
        return <form onSubmit={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}>
        <input type="text" name="updatedItem" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.id} />
        <input type="text" name="updatedItem1" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.name} />
        <input type="text" name="updatedItem2" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.age} />
        <input type="text" name="updatedItem3" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.email} />
        <button className="update-add-item">Update</button> 
        </form>    }  }
         handleClose(){
            this.setState({view:!this.state.view})
          }




    render()
    {
     return(
     <div> 


          <Dialog  open>
          <DialogTitle>Edit The Details</DialogTitle>
              <form>
              <label >ID</label>
                   <input type="number"  name="id" className="item"  />
                 <label>Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="item" className="item"  />
                   <label>age</label>
                   <input type="number" name="xyz" className="item"  />
                   <label>email</label>
                   <input type="text" name="email" className="item"  />  
                   <button className="btn-add-item" >Add</button> 

                  </form>
                  <Button onClick={this.handleClose.bind(this)} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button></Dialog>   


     </div> )

    }

}
export default EditDialog;
```

I have used Callback function and passing the updating function.
But for the EditDialog box,the details arent autopopulating and also i need to perform the update in dialog box and publish the result back.

Answer (score 1):

**A Problem:**

You put your `<EditDialog />` into your Array loop (`students.map`) in the file `ToDo.js`, so when your state (`state.editview`) becomes `true` you have 5 dialogs that are shown together, so you cannot see the first one.

So lets put it outside of your loop (map):

```
// FROM HERE
</tr>))
}
</table>
// TO HERE
{this.state.editview? <EditDialog updDetails={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}/>:null}
</div>
```

**Your Answer:**

You should pass the current student as a props to your dialog, so you can view the one that is clicked. Something similar to your `onDeleteHandle` function. Do the steps below:

**1)** Add a state of your `currentStudent` to your `ToDo` state:

```
state = {
        edit: false, id: null, view: false, editview: false,
        students: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com'},
            {id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com'},
            {id: 5, name: 'kiwi', age: 20, email: 'kiwi@email.com'}
        ],
        currentStudent: {} // ADD THIS ONE
    }
```

**2)** Pass your student ID to your function `editFormDialog` just like your delete one: `(abc.id)`

```
<button onClick={this.editFormDialog.bind(this, abc.id)}>Edit</button>
```

**3)** In your `editFormDialog` function find your student just like the one you did in `onUpdateHandle` but this time you have to find the equal ID and update your `currentStudent` state:

```
editFormDialog() {

        let id = arguments[0]; // Or better to pass it as a parameter: editFormDialog(id) { ... }
        this.setState({
            currentStudent: this.state.students.filter(item => {
                if (item.id === id) { // IDs should be Equal
                    return item;
                }
            })
        });

        this.setState({editview: !this.state.editview})
    }
```

**4)** Now you have your `currentStudent` in your state. So you have to have it in your `<EditDialog />`, and so you can access it into your `EditDialog` class (EditDialog.js). Add a property to your `<EditDialog />`, I named it `currentStudent` like this:

```
{
    this.state.editview
        ? <EditDialog
            currentStudent={this.state.currentStudent} // THIS PROPERTY
            updDetails={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}
        />
        : null
}
```

**5)** Now you can access your currentStudent in the `EditDialog` class like this:

```
// Add a State to EditDialog
this.state = {
      editDetails: true,
      view: false,
      updatedValues: {
           id: null,
           email: null
      }
}

// We use this to Mount it for the first time (Prevent Loop Renders)    
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        updatedValues: {
            id: this.props.currentStudent[0].id,
            email: this.props.currentStudent[0].email
        }
    });
}

// We should do this to update the input value to the state
<input type="text" name="email" className="item" onInput={this.updateStateHandler} value={this.state.updatedValues.email}/>

// And we of course need the updateHandler method
updateStateHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        updatedValues: {
            ...this.state.updatedValues,
            email: e.target.value
        }
    });
};
```

I've just filled the email input in the `render()` method. You could fill the other ones too.

**6)** Now for passing the data back to the your ToDo and update the table with the new values, you have to add `handleUpdate` method in your dialog like this:

```
handleUpdate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.closeModal();
    this.props.updateStudentHandler(this.state.updatedValues);
}
```

**7)** So you need to pass `closeModal` and `updateStudentHandler` from your ToDo class. Your EditDialog should be something like this:

```
<EditDialog
      currentStudent={this.state.currentStudent}
      updDetails={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}
      updateStudentHandler={this.updateStudent}
      closeModal={this.closeModal}
/>
```

And the handlers:

```
updateStudent = (updatedValues) => {

    let newStudents = [...this.state.students];
    newStudents.map(
        student => {
            if (student.id === updatedValues.id) {
                student.email = updatedValues.email;
            }
        }
    );

    this.setState({
        students: newStudents
    });
}

closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
        editview: false
    });
}
```

**NOTE 1:** To closing the dialog, I saw that you change the state of the EditDialog class which was wrong. You should handle that in your ToDo state like the closeModal method at the top.

**NOTE 2:** To access `this` in the methods above, you should use ES6 arrow functions.

At last your `ToDo` and `EditDialog` classes should look like this:

**ToDo.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Todo.css'
import EditDialog from './EditDialog'
import FormDialog from './FormDialog'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import {thisExpression} from '@babel/types';

class Todo extends Component {

    state = {
        edit: false, id: null, view: false, editview: false,
        students: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com'},
            {id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com'},
            {id: 5, name: 'kiwi', age: 20, email: 'kiwi@email.com'}
        ],
        currentStudent: {}
    }

    onDeleteHandle() {
        let id = arguments[0];
        this.setState({
            students: this.state.students.filter(item => {
                if (item.id !== id) {
                    return item;
                }
            })
        });
    }

    onUpdateHandle(id, name, age, email) {

        this.setState({
            students: this.state.students.map(item => {
                if (item.id === this.state.id) {
                    item['id'] = id;
                    item['name'] = name;
                    item['age'] = age;
                    item['email'] = email;
                }
                return item;
            })
        })
        this.setState({edit: false});
    }

    signUpDialog() {
        this.setState({view: !this.state.view})
    }

    editFormDialog(id) {

        // let id = arguments[0];
        this.setState({
            currentStudent: this.state.students.filter(item => {
                if (item.id === id) {
                    return item;
                }
            })
        });

        this.setState({editview: !this.state.editview})
    }

    updateStudent = (updatedValues) => {

        let newStudents = [...this.state.students];
        newStudents.map(
            student => {
                if (student.id === updatedValues.id) {
                    student.name = updatedValues.name;
                    student.age = updatedValues.age;
                    student.email = updatedValues.email;
                }
            }
        );

        this.setState({
            students: newStudents
        });
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            editview: false
        });
    }

    renderEditForm() {
        if (this.state.edit) {
            return <form onSubmit={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}>
                <input type="text" name="updatedItem" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.id}/>
                <input type="text" name="updatedItem1" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.name}/>
                <input type="text" name="updatedItem2" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.age}/>
                <input type="text" name="updatedItem3" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.email}/>
                <button className="update-add-item">Update</button>
            </form>
        }
    }

    onEditHandle(event) {
        this.setState({edit: true, id: arguments[0], name: arguments[1], age: arguments[2], email: arguments[3]});
    }

    onSubmitHandle(id, name, age, email) {

        this.setState({
            students: [...this.state.students, {
                id: id,
                name: name,
                age: age,
                email: email
            }]
        })
    };

    render() {
        return <div style={{width: "500px", background: "beige"}}>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                {
                    this.state.students.map(abc => (<tr key={abc.id}>
                        <td>{abc.id}</td>
                        <td>{abc.name}</td>
                        <td>{abc.age}</td>
                        <td>{abc.email}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button onClick={this.onDeleteHandle.bind(this, abc.id)}>Delete</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button onClick={this.editFormDialog.bind(this, abc.id)}>Edit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>))
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>

            {
                this.state.editview
                    ? <EditDialog
                        currentStudent={this.state.currentStudent}
                        updDetails={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}
                        updateStudentHandler={this.updateStudent}
                        closeModal={this.closeModal}
                    />
                    : null
            }

        </div>
    }
}

export default Todo;
```

**EditDialog.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

class EditDialog extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editDetails: true,
            view: false,
            updatedValues: {
                id: null,
                name: null,
                age: null,
                email: null
            }
        }
    }

    onUpdateHandle(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            students: this.state.students.map(item => {
                if (item.id === this.state.id) {
                    item['id'] = event.target.updatedItem.value;
                    item['name'] = event.target.updatedItem1.value;
                    item['age'] = event.target.updatedItem2.value;
                    item['email'] = event.target.updatedItem3.value;
                }
                return item;
            })
        })
        this.setState({edit: false});
    }

    renderEditForm() {
        if (this.state.editDetails) {
            return <form onSubmit={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}>
                <input type="text" name="updatedItem" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.id}/>
                <input type="text" name="updatedItem1" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.name}/>
                <input type="text" name="updatedItem2" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.age}/>
                <input type="text" name="updatedItem3" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.email}/>
                <button className="update-add-item">Update</button>
            </form>
        }
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({view: !this.state.view})
    }

    handleUpdate(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.closeModal();
        this.props.updateStudentHandler(this.state.updatedValues);
    }

    updateStateHandler = (e) => {
        let newUpdatedValues = {};
        switch (e.target.name) {
            case 'name':
                newUpdatedValues = {
                    ...this.state.updatedValues,
                    name: e.target.value
                };
                break;
            case 'age':
                newUpdatedValues = {
                    ...this.state.updatedValues,
                    age: e.target.value
                };
                break;
            case 'email':
                newUpdatedValues = {
                    ...this.state.updatedValues,
                    email: e.target.value
                };
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        this.setState({
            updatedValues: newUpdatedValues
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            updatedValues: {
                id: this.props.currentStudent[0].id,
                name: this.props.currentStudent[0].name,
                age: this.props.currentStudent[0].age,
                email: this.props.currentStudent[0].email
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Dialog open>
                    <DialogTitle>Edit The Details</DialogTitle>
                    <form>
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input type="number" name="id" className="item"
                               value={this.state.updatedValues.id} />
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" className="item"
                               onInput={this.updateStateHandler}
                               value={this.state.updatedValues.name} />
                        <label>age</label>
                        <input type="number" name="age" className="item"
                               onInput={this.updateStateHandler}
                               value={this.state.updatedValues.age} />
                        <label>email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" className="item"
                               onInput={this.updateStateHandler}
                               value={this.state.updatedValues.email} />
                        <button className="btn-add-item" onClick={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)}>Add</button>

                    </form>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleClose.bind(this)} color="primary">
                        Cancel
                    </Button></Dialog>
            </div>)
    }

}

export default EditDialog;
```

Comment: @Vahid..its working correctly and the data is auto populating.Once the form is submitted in the dialog it is calling uponFormSubmit() which is suppose to pass the  values from dialog to onUpdateHandle () in Todo component.I am using this code. <DialogTitle>Edit The Details</DialogTitle><form onSubmit={this.uponFormSubmit}><<4 fields> calling the funtion as defined below :uponFormSubmit(event){
      alert("help")
      event.preventDefault();
    this.props.updDetails(
      event.target.id.value,
      ......);Still I am not able to pass the values to my call back function

Comment: Also I am not able to update/edit values which have been auto populated in the dialog box

Comment: Sure Vahid..but right now i am unable to post anything as i cant post anything for next 90 mins.Can you help

Comment: I will update the current answer based on your request.

Comment: i tried using "Value" instead of "value" in the <label >ID</label>
                   <input  type="number"  name="id" className="item" Value={this.props.currentStudent[0].id} /> and it seems I am able to edit the data but the issue still persists it should call form submit and update data correspondingly in the opening page.

Comment: @aakritipriya I have updated the answer. Now you can change your data and see changes on your table.

Comment: i have updated my code as you instructed.But my problem is I am only able to update my email .ID,,name,age is not being updated.updateStateHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({ updatedValues: [...this.state.updatedValues,{
                id:e.target.value,
                email: e.target.value
            }
        ]
        });
    }; getting error for updateStateHandler()

Comment: GETTING ERROR AS  this,state.updatedValues is not iterable

Comment: @aakritipriya I've said that I only provide the email for test. Anyway, I updated the answer for all of your properties. Just copy ToDo.js and EditDialog.js to your code and see them in action.

Comment: @aakritipriya You shouldn't change the ID as it is our KEY to find the row which we want to be edited (notice the (student.id === updatedValues.id) statement). So if you mean that you want to change the Student ID for example, you may create another property (for instance "StudentID") and change that instead of the Key ID itself.